# parsing json like data without creating a json file python

Tags: python, json, pandas, web-scraping

I am scraping some data and I was looking to automate some things. At the moment my scraper creates JSON files (one for each page I scrape) which I clean and put together into a CSV which I then analyze. I am trying to clean the JSON like data without saving it to a JSON file.

At the moment I am writing a JSON file and then using pd.read_json and then cleaning and transforming it. What I was hoping to do was to call the scrapers and have them return the contents of the JSON file rather than writing a JSON file and then loading the JSON file.

current code is something like this:

scrape...

```
with open('%s-%s-df1.json'%(arg1, arg2), 'w) as fp:
    json.dump(df1, fp, indent = 4)
```

what I hope to achieve is to directly manipulate df1 without having to do the above. The reason I am having to do the above at the moment is because pd.read_json transforms the JSON file into a pandas data frame. How can I transform JSON like data without exporting to a json file and then importing using pd.read_json?

Comment: StringIO is one possibility, as it would support the `.read()` method that pandas' `.read_json()` expects.  (either the `StringIO` module in Python2 or `io` module in Python3)

Comment: Have you read [the docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html)? They explain where you can just use a string, where to use StringIO, and what the implications are for each. Any answer anyone gives here is going to be the same information in less detail, less authoritatively, and it will go stale unlike the docs. If you have a question the docs don’t answer, ask it specifically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pd.read_json` takes a file path or a string buffer, so you can pass the json string directly to it.